# Assembla And Perforce not working can't figure it out

Tags: perforce

So i am trying to use perforce with assembla, Everything is setup correctly but when i run p4v and try to connect it saids

"Unable to find destination depot
You must set P4HOST variable according to the rules
from your Perforce Tool information page"

I setup the environment variables for example i type "p4 info" and it displays the correct stuff i can also login using "p4 login"

but when i try to connect using p4v the visual client it saids

"Unable to find destination depot
You must set P4HOST variable according to the rules
from your Perforce Tool information page"

any help would be muchly appreciated. Note i also setup the environment variables in the p4config.txt i also set system environment variables and everything but i cant seem to get my visual gui client app to connect to the assembla perforce server.

Answer (score 2):

Nvm i solved it i just had to do this command with the full workspace directory

p4 set P4CONFIG="C:\workspace_directory\p4config.txt"

instead of just

p4 set P4CONFIG=p4config.txt